# PHP fopen() failed in combination session_start() and mysql_connect()

Tags: php, resources, debian

We have a problem on Debian server and PHP version 4.4.4-8+etch6. In this script (it is full script, not just part of code):

```
mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass'); 
session_start(); 

$h = fopen('http://www.google.com/robots.txt', 'r'); 
var_dump(fread($h, 40));
```

If I comment out `mysql_connect`, it works. If i comment out session_start, it works.
If `mysql_connect` failed (bad user and password) `fopen` works too. But with both, fopen failed. So it is not related to DNS lookup.

There is a result

```
Warning: fopen(http://www.google.com/robots.txt) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! in /var/www/web4/rychtarka.cz/rychtarka.cz/test.php on line 9

Warning: fread(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /var/www/web4/rychtarka.cz/rychtarka.cz/test.php on line 10
bool(false)
```

I think, there is some resources limit in system, file descriptors or something. Our server administrator told us, it is skript error. Can you please point me to debian system change to repair.

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: What's the actual error?

Comment: What error does it fail with?

Comment: allow `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and debug. There is bound to be some sort of error or notice.

Comment: oh, i'am sorry.. result is now in question

Comment: I doubt very much this has anything to do with mysql_connect or session_start. `HTTP request failed!` is fairly clear. Have you tried this with other domains?

Comment: yes, we get same error on all virtualhosts on one server

Comment: No, I mean using another site to fetch the data from instead of Google

Comment: Yes, originally we use it for fetching RSS feed. It goes wrong with any remote file. This short code was created with half interval method :) to find only things, that is responsible for error. In time it starts, my teammate in communication with provider told me, that 'To many open files.' error displayed (don't know if in apache log/syslog/PHP error). Once we try to restart server, but it doesn't help. Bad situation, we have no root access to system.

Comment: ..but when mysql_connect or session_start is removed, fetch any file is succesfull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally (after 3 days) we fixed the error. We traced it using 'php -f test.php' which pointed to Apache's limit on max open files.

We raised number via `ulimit` from 1024 to 8k and after a restart everything worked great.

Comment: you could have also make a custom-php.ini, which you load in a .htaccess (all in the same folder)